# How do I redirect after login only if the user logged in from a certain page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm on WordPress, and I'm trying to redirect the user after login, but only if they signed in from a certain page (slug is 'upgrade-now-gold-class-coaching')

Here is what I have made so far:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //did they try to login from this page?
    if ( $request == "upgrade-now-gold-class-coaching" ) {
        //is there a user to check?
        if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            //check for admins
            if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
                // redirect them to the default place
                return $redirect_to;
            } else {
                return "https://www.drewbairdfitness.com/11674-2/";
            }
        } else {
            return $redirect_to;
        }
    } else  {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where you put your login form? is it in your certain page or you still use default login form ( wp-admin/wp-login.php ) ?

Comment: It's on a different page; it's actually on '/upgrade-now-gold-class-coaching/' - I'm planning to have multiple login pages; and want each of them to redirect somewhere else after login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Jared Codling*, fire [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) to redirect early, you can use [`wp_safe_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) . Here a couple sample approach redirection if request login from a certain page to another page and if the user role NOT as `administrator`.

**Redirect to page use its url:**

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    /* target certain page with their part url
     * you can use url_to_postid( $request )
     * and pass in conditional statement with your target post id
     * target post/page id = 7
     * if ( 7 == url_to_postid( $request ) )
     * make it sure you have hidden input name redirect_to
    */
    if ( false !== strpos( $request, 'upgrade-now-gold-class-coaching' )
        && ! empty( $user->roles ) )
    {
        /* exclude administrator as role
         *  
        */
        if ( is_array( $user->roles )
            && ! in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
        {
            /* redirect to another url
             * we use hardcode slug
            */
            $redirect_to = home_url( '/11674-2/' );
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to, 302 );
            exit;
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

**Redirect to page use its id:**

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    /* target certain page with their part url */
    if ( false !== strpos( $request, 'upgrade-now-gold-class-coaching' )
        && ! empty( $user->roles ) )
    {
        /* exclude administrator as role
         *  
        */
        if ( is_array( $user->roles )
            && ! in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) )
        {
            /* redirect to another url
             * you can use function get_page_link(40), mean page id 40
            */
            $redirect_to = get_page_link(40);
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to, 302 );
            exit;
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

**Note**: By fire filter function [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) and you use custom login form, just make sure you have hidden input name `redirect_to`, such as default wp login form in `wp-login.php`.